# Sum a calculation in query, but don't loose all records

Tags: sql

I did my final exam of programming in PHP today. Tomorrow is the second day. I almost completed the application, but I am missing one things, the most important thing. The application is a restaurant, where I can add reservations, make orders etc.

The final thing is that I have to show the receipt of a specific order.
I can do that, but somehow I can't get the total price.

This is my database (simplified)

Columns: name, quantity, price

Data:

Hotdog, 1, 2.00
Hamburger, 2, 4.00

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *, (quantity*price) AS total FROM products
```

So that adds another column behind both products, with the total price of the column.

Now, I want to count all the total prices together, so that after the total column, there is another column that shows all totals together.

I tried this

```
SELECT *, SUM(quantity*price) AS total FROM products
```

However, if I use SUM, it only displays one record, but I want both records. What do I need to do to make the query work, and that it shows the total price of all products together?

EDIT: Yes, I am allowed to ask questions if you don't know something.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why did you tag it as phpMyAdmin? Did you make accidental mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a sub select:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(quantity*price) FROM products) AS total FROM products
```

Comment: And what's the difference between your query and OP's query?

Comment: Also this will combine Hotdog and Hamburger total, which pretty sure is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Eric this is different from OP's query since it's getting the total ( SUM(quanity*price) ) and appending that to each row. Since SUM is an aggregate function it only returns one value, hence the one row for his result; he wants all rows.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use group by in times of using aggregate function

```
SELECT col1,col2, SUM(quantity*price) AS total FROM products
group by col1,col2
```

Comment: What do you mean with col1 and col2?

Comment: @Wesley i means other's selected column

Comment: @Wesley Really???  Replace `col1`, `col2` with whatever columns you to group the record by.  I think it's common sense.

Comment: Never worked with group by to be honest, thanks for the response!